# How do I spell Python package/module imports for this situation?

Tags: python, python-packaging

I have these Python files

```
project/packages/foo/job.py
project/packages/foo/models.py
project/packages/foo/stuff/Thing.py
```

models.py contains `class Thing` and Thing.py contains functions related to `Thing`

job.py tries to do this:

```
from . import models
from . import stuff

def job ():
    x = models.Thing (123)
    stuff.Thing.related_function (x)
```

This yields an error:

> AttributeError: module 'foo.stuff' has no attribute 'Thing'

I've tried variations on the import spellings but can't get it to work. I want to *not* bring `Thing` into the namespace, but always have to refer to it as `models.Thing` or `stuff.Thing`

How do I do this?

Comment: you need an `__init__.py` in your `stuff` directory in order to make it act as a package. If you have `from . import Thing` in that `__init__.py` you can then do `import stuff; stuff.Thing`.

Comment: `Thing` is a module in the `stuff` package and you never imported it, so it's not available. Try `from .stuff import Thing`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `__init__` files:

```
project/packages/foo/__init__.py
project/packages/foo/job.py
project/packages/foo/models.py
project/packages/foo/stuff/__init__.py
project/packages/foo/stuff/Thing.py
```

In the `stuff` package, initialise the submodule by adding this line:

```
# in project/packages/foo/stuff/__init__.py file
from foo.stuff import Thing
```

The other `__init__.py` can be empty.

Now in your `job.py` code, the `models.Thing` attribute should resolve (it's a class) and `stuff.Thing` attribute should resolve (it's a submodule).

*Note:* It is not a good naming convention to have a module name matching the class, within the same project - that's unnecessarily confusing.  I recommend to rename the `Thing` submodule for "functions related to `Thing`" to something else, maybe `thing_helpers`.